# Including CSS files in PDF using wicked_pdf helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I am successfully loading CSS files in my PDF file using wicked_pdf gem helpers:

```
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "pdf" %>
```

This works great in development, however when i deploy in production the pdf CSS file is not correctly imported.  Also note that the file is "pdf.scss.erb" and not just "pdf.css".

I am not sure how to fix this problem. Looking at the server logs, i do not see any missed file warnings.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this one out? I also ran into this issue :(

Comment: no @jdgray, what i did was to use the helper in development, which generates the embedded CSS, and then i had to copy paste it into the html file so in production is there too

Comment: You should use the latest gem version, we also updated slightly the documentation to make it more easy to understand how to use in production!

Answer (score 0):

I myself solved the problem by duplicating the styles right onto the layout page.

However at [this](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/516) github thread people are advising to do several things:

Include the files in your precompile list in `config/initializers/assets.rb` as [described](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#asset-pipeline-usage) in the Asset pipeline usage section of the README.

Using `stylesheet_link_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64('pdf')`

Comment: yepp, with version `1.1.0` things works fine now! :)

Answer (score -1):

wkthmltopdf not bundling with dependency library to wkthmltopdf can install the gem after installed gem run bundle install

```
gem "wkhtmltopdf-binary"
```